How do we test multi-tenant Teams apps?
I've written a Teams SaaS app using the teams toolkit and as you know, it's tied to the test tenant of your developer account. So that's how I've been developing it and debugging it etc.
But it's not clear to me what I need to do in order to test that this app will work across multiple tenants. I particularly want to test things like permissions, SSO and fetching of access tokens etc
Does anyone have any tips?

You can follow this instruction to enable multi-tenant support in Teams Toolkit. Basically there are four steps:

[For Tab project] Create CDN and update application id uri for Microsoft Entra app
[For Tab project with Azure Function with backend] Update Azure Function and add Tab domain in CORS allowed origins
Update aad.manifest.json file, set value of AzureADMultipleOrgs to signInAudience
Update infra/azure.parameter.${env}.json, set value of m365TenantId to common

